# After accidentally ejecting an external drive, can I remount it, as a regular user?

Tags: mount

I know I can do the following:

```
$ su -
Password: ********
# fdisk -l
  < take a guess at the device name ... >
# mkdir -p /mnt/myssd
# chown mihai:mihai /mnt/myssd
# mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /mnt/myssd
# exit
$
```

However, I *shouldn't have* to do that. I mean, when I inserted the USB stick the first time, it was automatically mounted *somehow*, without me having to go through those contortions and run commands as root. So can I invoke the same magic manually, the second time?

(There always the option of unplugging the USB drive and plugging it in again. But where's the fun in that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
gvfs-mount -d /dev/sdb1
```

as regular user.